# The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database.

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence, database-administration

I try to configure Reporting Server without selecting SSL Certificate for MS SQL Server. Can any body tell me that is that possible to deploy SSRS Report for testing purpose if I dont have SSL Certificate information. Because I am getting below error!
"The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. (rsReportServerDatabaseUnavailable)"
.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I am still a little confused if the problem is with the ReportingService web service endpoint, where you deploy the report to, or the ReportServices database.

Comment: I thought that installing SSRS and creating a DB connection was supposed to generate the certificates.

Comment: I think you guys are referring to the "Web Services Url".

Comment: Yes , for Web Services Url

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a certificate if one is applied to the service endpoint.

1. Open Reporing Service Configuration Manager.
2. under the targeted ssrs instance, navigate to the "Web Sercvices Url".
3. Make sure the SSL certificate is set to
4. Save the settings.

Also, make sure the database configured under the "Database" node is accesible from your SSRS instance.

Comment: Actually I do not have Certificate for SQL , using trial version only for learning purpose. Is this creating problem with deploying Report?

Comment: No, it sounds like your SSRS database is either on another server and not accessible to SSRS Server or you renamed the database or it has never been configured. What does the database instance name look like in the SSRS configuration manager?

Comment: thanks for the detail answers,it was due to  report server was never configured. Now i configured it and it is working properly. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the database is configured correctly in reporting services configuration manager.
If you updated the service account after the installation you probably want to use SQL Server Configuration Manager to update the account as it also sets the required permissions.

Regarding the SSL - reporting services encrypts the database using this certificate. as long as you are not importing the database or recovering from backup you can use the autogenerated certificate and deploy your projects from SSMS.

Comment: Make sure that the files ReportServerTempDB.mdf and ReportServerTempDB_log.ldf are uncompressed.